# How do I see item ids and durability?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I am trying to see how to toggle item and block ids in Minecraft 1.12.2 to help when I use WorldEdit, yet when I try to do what everyone says, which is F3 and H, nothing happens, and I am on a laptop, so I have a Fn key, and when I push Fn and F3 and H, still nothing. Am I doing something wrong, or does this not work for my computer?

Comment: First of all, what OS are you using?

Answer (score 0):

F3+H-but this feature is only on Java edition. You might be using Bedrock Edition.

Comment: The OP already mentions this doesn't work.